# Blank page in manage categories

Tags: php, magento

When I try to enter the administrator manage categories in magento the log shows:

```
Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: 
Filename cannot be empty  in 
/home/offevent/www/www/temporal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php 
on line 235
```

Comment: Did you recently change a layout xml file? Maybe you forgot to set a phtml template.

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 235 in /home/offevent/www/www/temporal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php, there probably is a reference to a file, you should start there your investigation.

Comment: On the server open the Template.php file in the given path and go the line 235. Please tell me what do you see there. I am not a magento user but I am willing to help.